# command to compile c files with .a files

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I have several .c files and one .a object file. What command with gcc should I use to compile them to one exe file? If we use a makefile, how will it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .a file is a library, already compiled.  You compile your .c file to a .o, then you use the linker to link your .o with the .a to produce an executable.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question about *how* to do it. Doesn't say "how it will look like".

Answer (score 22):

For simple cases you can probably do this:

```
gcc -o maybe.exe useful.a something.c
```

Makefiles for non-trivial projects usually first invoke gcc to compile each .c file to a .o object.

```
gcc -c something.c
```

Then they invoke the linker (these days often using gcc as a wrapper for it) with a list of .o and .a files to link into an output executable.

```
gcc -o maybe.exe useful.a something.o
```

Note also that for most installed libraries, it's typical not to explicitly specify the .a file but instead to say -lhandy which would be short for "try to find something called libhandy.a in the configured (or specified with -L) search directories"

Comment: Thanks to anonymous for catching the error in the object file generation

Answer (score 7):

`*.a` is a static library and not dynamic (`*.dll` in windows and `*.so` in linux)

```
gcc -L<here comes the library path> -l<library name>
```

for example for the file you have libname.a in the current path you should use:

```
gcc *.c -L. -lname -o myprogram.o
```

from the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) (put man gcc in the shell command prompt)

> You can mix options and other arguments. For the most part, the order
>   you use doesn't matter. Order does matter when you use several options
>   of the same kind; for example, if you specify -L more than once, the
>   directories are searched in the order specified. Also, the placement
>   of the -l option is significant.

Comment: Changed `gcc -L<here comes the library path> -l<library name>` from `gcc -l <here comes the library path> -l<library name>`. Hope that is what you meant

Comment: Why do you use `-lname` if the library is `libname.a`?

Comment: @this In gcc-speak, `-lfoo` means `libfoo.a` or `libfoo.so`. As for why gcc does it, I have no idea.