# Compiling simple C++ file with .a files?

Tags: c++, gcc

I've seen many following references: 
[command to compile c files with .a files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454263/command-to-compile-c-files-with-a-files)

I have a `.cpp` file I am trying to compile. I have in addition to this the `.h` file and 2 `.a` files.

```
g++ 1_SDKinfo.cpp -L. -l l* -o a.out -v

g++ 1_SDKinfo.cpp -L ../Lib/mac32_64 -lR3DSDK -lR3dSDKllvm -o a.out -v
```

I've tried many variants of this, but keep getting errors like

```
ld: library not found for -llibR3DSDK.a

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

## Directory of Files

```
1_SDKinfo.cpp       R3DSDKDecoder.h     R3DSDKOpenCL.h      REDCuda.dylib       REDR3D.dylib
R3DSDK.h        R3DSDKDefinitions.h R3DSDKRocket.h      REDDecoder.dylib    libR3DSDK.a
R3DSDKCuda.h        R3DSDKMetadata.h    R3DSDKStream.h      REDOpenCL.dylib     libR3DSDKllvm.a
```

How exactly am I supposed to compile this?
edit: mac os

Comment: If this is a case sensitive filesystem then `-lR3dSDKllvm` will not find `libR3DSDKllvm.a` because of the different case. You need `-lR3DSDKllvm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all the library you want to link with is in the current directory (it seems) so you should be using `.` as the argument to `-L`, to add the current directory to the library search path.

The second problem is that the name of a library is ***not*** the same as the file name. For a file named like `libR3DSDK.a` the *library name* is `R3DSDK`. The linker automatically adds the `lib` prefix and `.a` suffix.

So your command should be like

```
g++ 1_SDKinfo.cpp -L. -lR3DSDK -o a.out -v
```

*Or*

```
g++ 1_SDKinfo.cpp libR3DSDK.a -o a.out -v
```

The first command uses the `-L` and `-l` options to name the *library*, and the path where to find it. The second command doesn't use any special options, but instead list the *file* to link with.

Comment: Seem to be getting ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: @RyanHack That's another problem for another question (which most likely will be closed as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)), and probably means you forgot to link with some library.